# Absolute Phrase and 'With'

Tags: phrases, modifiers

I've been reading up on absolute phrases recently, and I was wondering if the following construction is grammatically correct:

> "Jared went to bed with a lot on his mind, each thought brimming with sadness and regret."

I would normally think that there should be a *with* after the comma, but the overabundance of the word in other parts of the sentence seem to make a third *with* redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems fine to me. In this type of construction, *with* is often elided but still implied. Compare:

> Freddy entered the office feeling agitated, [with] his mind no longer on the three-o'clock deadline but on the evening's assignation that he was now anticipating.
>
> Kelly came hobbling down the hallway towards them, [with] her foot dragging and [with] her paralysed arm swinging limply above the decayed linoleum.