# What is the grammatical ground for this prepositional phrase?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

In below formal excerpt,  how the first part, bolded, can be thought grammatically:

**With personnel an enduring target of violence**, we must work together to ensure our safety.

It is structured this way:
Prepositional phrase + noun [phrase] + noun [phrase].

Should not it have been written this way:
With personnel **becoming** an enduring target of violence, we must work together to ensure our safety.

Usually, the "with prepositional phrases" come in the following structures:

- With + noun + adjective [phrase], as in:

- We lay in bed with the window open. (indicating position or state somebody in).
- With John away there’s more room in the house. (indicating reason)

- With + noun + participle + noun, as in:

- I can’t do my homework with all this noise going on. (Reason).
- We jumped into the water with bullets whizzing past our ears. (what is happening at the time of an action).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Absolute Phrase and 'With'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168153/absolute-phrase-and-with) // See also [Is 'being' omitted in certain participle clauses and absolute constructions?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/582876/is-being-omitted-in-certain-participle-clauses-and-absolute-constructions) 'With personnel being an enduring target of violence, ....' /  'Personnel being an enduring target of violence, ....'  / 'With personnel an enduring target of violence, ....'  are all acceptable and equivalent in meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to EL&U. Please remember to include a source and context for your example.

> With personnel an enduring target of violence, we must work together to ensure our safety.

The sentence perfectly acceptable and requires no modification.

It is fronted by the prepositional (adverbial) phrase *"**With** personnel an enduring target of violence"* that modifies the main clause *"we must work together to ensure our safety."*

The clause also contains a reduced relative clause: *personnel an enduring target*, which, in full, is *"personnel **who are** an enduring target"*.

This omission is relatively common.

The sentence can be fronted by changing the phrase to a clause of purpose and can be understood as

"**As or because we are accompanied by** personnel *who are* an enduring target of violence, we must work together to ensure our safety".

Compare "**With** 1000 litres of water needed for the journey, we will have to have a truck. = "**As or because we are accompanied by** 1000 litres of water *that is* needed for the journey, we will have to have a truck.

Comment: Just because the construction includes the word ***with*** needn't imply *"we are **accompanied by**"* (personnel / water). The actual meanings of these prepositional phrases are ***Given that** personnel **are** an enduring target of violence...*, and ***Given that** 1000 litres of water **are** needed for the journey..*. We can see this by noting that *With all our truck drivers on strike, we will have to use a van* is fine - equivalent to ***Given that** all our truck drivers **are** on strike...* OR *All our truck drivers **being** on strike...*

Comment: The _with_ phrase is not a modifier. It's functioning as a supplementary adjunct, more specifically an adjunct of implicated reason. It gives the reason for the matrix situation.

Comment: Further, I wouldn't say that _personnel an enduring target_ is a 'reduced' relative clause but an NP headed by "personnel", and "an enduring target" as complement, cf. "with personnel being an enduring target of violence".

Comment: @FumbleFingers "With" invariably indicates an accompaniment of some sort. In your example it is the circumstances that accompany.

Comment: @BillJ I'm sure that CGEL expresses one possible interpretation but, given the nature and style of the OP's question, the complexity might override the understanding. "Reduced relative clause" is a useful and assimilable phrase as any.

Comment: @BillJ *"The with phrase is not a modifier."* Preposition + NP = modifier. To many, you are making a distinction without a difference. The chances are that the OP does not know what an adjunct is.

Comment: (1) The so-called 'reduced relative clause' is a non-finite clause, whereas "an enduring target of violence" is an NP. so it's not even a clause.  (2) prep+noun phrases very often function as complements, cf. "the return [of the warriors]";  "her criticism [of my decision]; "the advent [of the steam engine]", and so on. The bracketed PPs in those examples are clearly complements, not modifiers.

Comment: I completely agree that *"With" invariably indicates an accompaniment of some sort.* But in this construction, it's more a *metaphoric* usage - ***with**  [something being **part of the context].*** So in my example, the fact of the truck drivers being on strike is part of the context. But *physically / logically*, those drivers are nowhere to be seen! They themselves aren't "with" anything.

Answer (score 0):

> [*With personnel an enduring target of violence*]*, we must work together*
> *to ensure our safety.*

You're on the right lines when you say 'reason'.

The comma marks the *with* phrase as a supplement, one set off from the rest of the clause by broken intonation and punctuation.

Semantically, the construction has a general circumstantial meaning, but which may be interpreted as giving the reason for the matrix situation.

For this reason, it's best analysed as being an adjunct of implicated reason.